# Xamarin.Forms Selected Item is null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

This is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="InstagramCloneInterviewApp.MainPage"
             x:Name="CurrentPage"
             Title="Photos">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout>
                <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
             Command="{Binding LoadRefreshCommand}">
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Photos}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhoto}" RemainingItemsThreshold="{Binding CounterData}" RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding LoadNewPhotosCommand}" >
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                          
                                    <Grid   Padding="10">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                             <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CurrentPage}, Path=BindingContext.LoadSelectedPhotoCommand}" />
                                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="50" Source="{Binding Url}"  Grid.Column="0"></Image>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                            
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </RefreshView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Frame IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" BorderColor="#3498DB" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="#eeeeee">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></ActivityIndicator>
                        <Label TextColor="#3498DB" Text="Loading Data, Please Wait..." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
 
</ContentPage>
```

This is `SelectedPhoto` object in the ViewModel:

```
        public Photo SelectedPhoto
        {
            get { return selectedPhoto; }
            set
            {
                if (selectedPhoto != value)
                {
                    selectedPhoto = value;
                    SetProperty(ref selectedPhoto, value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPhoto");
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the task i get from `Grid.TapGestureRecognizer` and `LoadSelectedPhotoCommand`:

```
        async Task ExecuteGetDetailsSelectedPhoto()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;
            try
            {
                var test= SelectedPhoto;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

`var test` is always null.

It looks like item is not clicked. Does anyone have a similar experience or better idea to fix this?

Comment: why do you need TapGestureRecognizer?  Why can't you just use CollectionView's SelectionChangedCommand?

Comment: I tried it is good. Just one simple bug, it is called when list is loading and in that time SelectedItem is null, but i wil catch that

Comment: How do you set the `SelectedPhoto` for the itemsource `Photos`? You could check the code sample for the collectionview SelectedItem. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT the problem was Grid TapGesture override all space and SelectMode not working. I fixed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Grid `TapGesture` override all space and SelectMode not working